# Pass an array as setter in Java

Tags: java, getter-setter

DITP 3113 class

```
package com.ditp3113;

import java.util.Scanner;//Scanner class takes input
public class Student {
    
    
    /////Decalartion of the fields
    
    private String studName;
    private String idNo;
    public static double[] marks =new double[3];//Stores marks of three tests// static to ensure this double can be used universally
    
    
    
    public Student(String studName,String idNo)
    {  ///Constructor that accepts student's name and id as arguments
        this.idNo=idNo;
        this.studName=studName;
        
        
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String []args) {
        
     model model[] =new model[3];
        
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        
        
        Student OmarObject=new Student("Omar","B0123345");
        Student HanaObject=new Student("Hamza","B06564788");
        
        System.out.println("Please enter 3 marks for Omar:");
        
        
        for (int i=0; i<3;i++) {
        
            marks[i]=input.nextDouble();
            
           System.out.println();
                
        }
    
         
    model[0].setMarks(marks);
        
    
    System.out.println("Please enter 3 marks for Hana");
        
        
        for (int j=0; j<3;j++) {//Stores 3 marks for 3 subjects
            
            marks[j]=input.nextDouble();
            
            System.out.println();
        
            
        }
        
        model[1].setMarks(marks);
      
        double[] OmarMarks =model[0].getMarks();
        for (int i = 0; i <OmarMarks.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(OmarMarks[i]);
            
         
        } 
        
        double[] HannaMarks =model[1].getMarks();
        for (int j = 0; j <HannaMarks.length; j++) {
            System.out.println(HannaMarks[j]);
        } 
        
        
    }

}
```

Model class(model.java)

```
package com.ditp3113;

public class model {
    
    private double[] marks;
    
    

    
    public void setMarks(double[] marks) {
        
        this.marks=marks;
    }
    
    public double[] getMarks() {
        
        return marks;
    }

    
    
    
}
```

When i run , the following error comes:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.ditp3113.model.setMarks(double[])" because "model[0]" is null
    at com.ditp3113.Student.main(Student.java:46)
```

Can you please assist me how to fix this problem?

Comment: Hint: where do you believe you're ever creating an instance of the `model` class? (As an aside, I'd also *strongly* advise you to start following Java naming conventions ASAP.)

Comment: I was trying to create an array of objects for model class. Model[0] stores details of student1, model[1] stores details of student 2....like this .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing `model = new model[3];`, you create an array with a size of 3. But, it's empty.

So, when you do `model[0]`, this will return null.

To fix this, you should set value, such as `model[0] = myModel;`. In your case, `model[0] = new model();` should works, but only for the first item (the second and third will always be null).

More informations about NPE for Java, it's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/10952503)

Comment: yes, it is working, but now the problem is :Please enter 3 marks for Omar:
1

2

3

Please enter 3 marks for Hana
1

2

4

1.0
2.0
4.0
1.0
2.0
4.0
  3 is missing - the last values are saved only

Comment: model[0].setMarks(marks);- for first studet

Comment: model[1].setMarks(marks);-for second student....output show the second student values only TWICE.....

Comment: okay, i figured out the problem, it is solved now.Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't reply. I'm happy to see that it solve your issue ! But, I'm not here to do your homework for you, so if you have issue you can ask a new question, and explain where you are stuck.